Change color of whole table
I've been trying to change the colour of my table to dark grey for some time, but unfortunately without success. No matter what I do, it stays black. Both the text and the lines should be in dark grey. How can I do that? This is my code:
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[lmargin,rmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}

\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{A9A9A9}

% TikZ settings
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc,tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{shaded}
    \small \textcolor{darkgrey}{\textbf{Example Cont'd:} \lipsum[1]}
    \begin{center}
        \captionsetup{font=small,labelfont={color=darkgrey,bf}}
        \captionsetup[table]{hypcap=false}
                        
        \captionof{table}{\textcolor{darkgrey}{Title}.}
        \label{tab:example_rec}
        \vspace{-0.5cm}
                        
        \[
            \begin{array}
                {@{\hspace{1.0em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{2.5em}}c@{\hspace{1em}}}
                \toprule
                \text{Day}                                & \text{$\ldots$} & \text{$d=4$}                & \text{$d=5$}                            & \text{$d=6$}                            & \text{$d=7$}                            & \text{$d=8$}                                   & \text{$\ldots$} \\
                \midrule
                \text{{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont Task}} & \text{$\ldots$} & \text{\textit{Operational}} & \tikzmarknode{T2}{\text{\textit{Idle}}} & \tikzmarknode{T3}{\text{\textit{Idle}}} & \tikzmarknode{T4}{\text{\textit{Idle}}} & \tikzmarknode{T5}{\text{\textit{Operational}}} & \text{$\ldots$} \\[6pt]
                \text{$b_{d}$}                            & \text{$\ldots$} & \text{$1$}                  & \tikzmarknode{B2}{\text{$1$}}           & \tikzmarknode{B3}{\text{$0$}}           & \tikzmarknode{B4}{\text{$0$}}           & \tikzmarknode{B5}{\text{$0$}}                  & \text{$\ldots$} \\[6pt]
                \text{$r_{d}$}                            & \text{$\ldots$} & \text{$0$}                  & \tikzmarknode{R2}{\text{$0$}}           & \tikzmarknode{R3}{\text{$0$}}           & \tikzmarknode{R4}{\text{$0$}}           & \tikzmarknode{R}{\text{$1$}}                   & \text{$\ldots$} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{array}
        \]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]      
            \draw[thick, rounded corners] 
            ($(B3.north west)+(-0.07,0.07)$) rectangle ($(B5.south east)+(0.07,-0.07)$);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{shaded}

\end{document}


This example generates an error. You need to specify the width of the lmargin in geometry. You also should be using tabular rather than array here! That eliminates all the spurious vspace you had to take back out, and it's text mode rather than math mode so you can take out the \text commands.

Instead of using \textcolor{darkgray}{...} to change the colour of some parts of your box, you could use \color{darkgray} to change the text colour in the whole box:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{HTML}{DDDDDD}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{HTML}{A9A9A9}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{shaded}
\begingroup
    \color{darkgrey}
    \small \textbf{Example Cont'd: \lipsum[1]}
    \captionsetup{font=small,labelfont={color=darkgrey,bf}}
    \captionof{table}{\color{darkgrey}Caption}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    a & b\\
    \midrule
    c & d\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\par
\endgroup
\end{shaded}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}


